# Why FormShown event does not get fired in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.
I have `Form1` and `Form2`. In `form1` I use the following code to show `form2`:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    frm2.Show();
}
```

What I want is: I want to do some activities when `Form2` is shown every time. I placed `messageBox` in the `Form2Shown` event (for a test) but it only gets fired once and next time I show `Form2` it never get fired. I also tried to use `formLoad` but it only get fired once and next time I show `form2` it never get fired.
I know I can use frm2.ShowDialog() to fire shown event every time but I do not want for some reasons.

```
private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form2 is shown"); // this gets fired only once when form2 is shown.
                                       // when I show form2 again it does not get fired.
}

private void button_Hide_Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // this is in form2
    Hide();
}
```

My question is: Anyone knows how to fire an event every time `form2` is shown? I am happy to obtain some new ideas to solve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you show some more code? Are you hiding `Form2` in between your clicks on `button1`?

Comment: @Franz Wimmer. yes I am hiding form2 afterI finishing using it. please see the updated code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed;
>   subsequently minimizing, maximizing, restoring, hiding, showing, or
>   invalidating and repainting will not raise this event.

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see what events are raised. And choose one which meets your requirements.

Some example.

**Form1** - two buttons, Show and Hide

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 frm = new Form2();

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Show();
    }

    private void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm.Hide();
    }
}
```

**Form2** - shows msgbox when shown. I change form close behavior to hide form not destroy.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Visible == true)
            MessageBox.Show("Hey");
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have inserted some comments to understand whats going on:

```
// You can use auto-property in here.
private Form2 frm2 { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new instance before it is shown.
    NewForm();
    frm2.Show();
}

// Creates a new instance and hooks the event.
private void NewForm()
{
    frm2 = new Form2();
    // When creating an instance, hook the load event.
    frm2.Load += Form2_Load;
}

// Will be triggered when show is called.
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about `Form2_Load`?

Comment: Why always create new form?

Comment: @UweKeim Msdn says: `(Load event) Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.` So yes, the trigger is correct.

Comment: @BWA He hasnt cleared out if he wants to have multiple instances or just one.

Comment: @C4u But she use  `// this is in form2
    Hide();` so, she wants to hide form. And if she always use new form shown works perfect.

Comment: @BWA the question got edited. On the first version it was about closing and opening again. Code wasnt visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need `Form2_Shown` in your `Form2` class, you should override [`OnActivated()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than use the EventHandler:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form2 is shown");
}
```

> The OnActivated method also allows derived classes to handle the event without attaching a delegate. Overriding this method is the preferred technique for handling the event in a derived class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still does not work with your code, it only fires once and next time I show form2 it does not get raised.

Comment: Sorry, I confused events. I updated my Answer to `OnActivated`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. we use Form2_VisibleChanged event:

```
 private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.Visible==true)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Form is visible");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Form is hiding");

        }


    }
```

Comment: Minimizing equals also to hiding, doesnt it? Therefore this is triggered more times than you have specified in your whished goal.

Comment: @C4u No, hide is hide, minimize is minimize.

Comment: NO. hide is hide.

Comment: Im sorry, I ment if visible is false when minimizing!?

Comment: @C4u no, when form is minimized still is visible but minimized.